# UISearchDisplayController not displaying any rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am trying to add a Search Bar to a UITableViewController derived class programmatically (I don't have a xib). When I tap the search bar, the table goes blank, and the keyboard appears. If I type a search term, debug messages tell me that the filtered array has the correct number of entries, but the view remains blank.

I have declared the UISearchDisplayController in the .h file as:
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchDisplayController *searchController;
Also, I have added the UISearchDisplayDelegate and  UISearchBarDelegate in the class def.

I have created the uisearchbar and UISearchDisplayController in viewDidLoad as follows:

```
UISearchBar *theSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[theSearchBar sizeToFit];
theSearchBar.delegate = self;
theSearchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = theSearchBar;

self.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc]
                         initWithSearchBar:theSearchBar
                         contentsController:self];
self.searchController.delegate = self;
self.searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
self.searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
//etc.;



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{   
    if (tableView == self.searchController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        rows = self.filteredPersons.count;
    }
    else 
    {
        rows = [(NSSet *)[self.cardList valueForKey:@"cards"] count];
    }
    return rows;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FLOG(@" called");

    UILabel *nameLabel = nil;
    bool filtering = NO;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PersonCell";

    MGSwipeTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
       cell = [[MGSwipeTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSArray *subviews = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:cell.contentView.subviews];
    for (UIView *subview in subviews)
    {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }

    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    NSInteger count = 0;
    Person *person;
    if (tableView == self.searchController.searchResultsTableView )
    {
        person = [self.filteredPersons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        person = [[self sortPersons] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
...

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    if (searchString.length==0)
    {
        self.filteredPersons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        return NO;
    }
    [self.filteredPersons removeAllObjects];
    if (searchString.length>0)
    {
        for (Person *person in self.sortPersons)
        {
            NSRange range = [person.compositeName rangeOfString:searchString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if (range.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [self.filteredPersons addObject:person];
            }
        }
    }
    NSLog (@" Filtered persons now %d", self.filteredPersons.count);

    return YES;
}
```

When I test this with a table with 4 rows, if I click into the searchbar, the keyboard appears, but table goes completely blank. Another thing which isn't right, debug messages show that numberOfRowsInSection is called a few times alternating between saying there are 4 rows, and 0 rows!
When I start typing, shouldReloadTableForSearchString does get called and seems to add the correct number of rows to the filtered array (two in the test i was running).
Using debug messages, I can see that cellForRowAtIndexPath is called twice,and finds the correct names in my filtered list, but the table remains blank. Also, numberOfRowsInSection gets called a few times, sometimes saying there are 2 rows, sometimes 4.

Please could someone give me some ideas on what I have done wrong, or how to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

The UISearchDisplayController is deprecated and replaced by UISearchController. I'd suggest checking out the UICatalog where you can see some nice sample code to accomplish the same thing in a more long-term supportable fashion.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html